# Thread Local variable in Singleton class

Tags: java, singleton, thread-local, thread-local-storage

In a singleton class , am having private static ThreadLocal variable. Whether that variable will be shared among users accessing that singleton class , Or won't be shared ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *users*. What i know is, each thread will have its context stored separately, so data corruption probability is less.

Comment: we are having a servlet implemented as singleton class. This class acts like a proxy between two applications. I am trying to introduce one ThreadLocal variable to capture login attempt , so that if other application is not available for some reason , error message should be thrown after some limit. Since this singleton class is instantiated once ,  all users accessing to this class will be sharing this threadlocal variable or not ? , is my question..

Answer (score 3):

Each thread that accesses the variable of singleton class object (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized copy of that variable, it woun't be shared and that is the character of `ThreadLocal` variable.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Answer (score 1):

ThreadLocal is different. SingleTon is different.

**ThreadLocal**

Even singleton object has different thread local in different thread.

For ex,

A is a singleton reference. A can be shared in multiple threads. So each thread has thread specific thread local value.

**Singleton**

Only one object exists in JVM at a time.

Comment: It's not **Single Ton**. It's **Singleton**.